# i cant use Swift_Mailer

Tags: symfony, symfony4, swiftmailer

[![**`**Undefined type 'Swift_Mailer'**i can t use swift mailer even i intalled  composer require symfony/swiftmailer-bundle , what should i do i followed the documentation and that didnt work**`**][1]][1]
Undefined type 'Swift_Mailer'**i can t use swift mailer even i intalled  composer require symfony/swiftmailer-bundle , what should i do i followed the documentation and that didnt work
, i get that error "Argument 1 passed to Swift_Mailer::__construct() must implement interface Swift_Transport, string given"
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uUM9.png

Answer (score 1):

on line 23, you‘re creating another instance of Swift_Mailer, instead of Swift_Message:

```
$message = (new \Swift_Message('Nouveau Contact'))
```

Comment: thanks a lot that was my bad i m codin for liike 12 hours and i can t see thing s clear as before so thanks again sir